# Accumulators(long) lost after job failure

Tags: apache-spark

I have created a spark job performing multiple operations and simultaneously gathering record count of each operations using long accumulators. I have implemented Spark listener to fetch information related to tasks, stages and jobs.
The onTaskEnd method in listener gives access to information of each task details such as id, status, accumulators.

For eg:

override def onTaskEnd(taskEnd: SparkListenerTaskEnd) {

taskEnd.taskInfo.accumulables.foreach(f => {
        println("Task End Status: " + taskEnd.taskInfo.status)
        LOG.info("Acc iD : " + f.id + " Acc name : " + f.name.get + " Acc value : " + f.value.get + " Acc update : "
          + f
          .update)
    })
}

The above code iterates all the available accumulators present inside a task and also print the task status 
such as RUNNING,SUCCESS,FAILED.

In my application a long accumulator is created for each processing unit. My goal is to identify the processing unit which has failed.

When a job fails, the failure tasks show failed status but dont show the long accumulators whereas inbuild accumulators such as internal.metrics.executorRunTimeaccumulator,internal.metrics.peakExecutionMemoryaccumulator,etc are accessible. 
I tried accessing the long accumulators in onTaskStart/onTaskEnd method of the listener, but they were not present in accumulables.

Hence, I am not able to identify the processing unit which has failed.

Could someone please let me know the reason why long accumulators are not present in accumulables post job failure.

Thanks,

Comment: Spark may drop accumulator updates when a task fails, e.g., an executor is lost. Could you describe your requirement? You may not need accumulators to identify the failed processing unit.

Comment: My requirement is to identify the operation/processing unit for which the task has failed. Currently I am identifying the processing unit from the accumulator name. Since I am not able to get the accumulators when task is failed. Could you please suggest some other way to identify the failed processing unit.